# Excel formula to calculate date difference in years and months

Tags: excel

I'm trying to come up with an Excel formula that will calculate the difference in years and months between a date in the past and today.

For example, the following tells me the number of days between a cell and now:

```
=INT((TODAY()-C2))
```

But I then need to format that value as Year and Month(s).

Obviously I'm no expert in Excel and appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: Look at the Text() function.  It works the same way Format() does in MSAccess

Comment: You could try the `DATEDIF` function.http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx

Comment: @DougGlancy, `Microsoft has decided not to document this function` - function-ghost:)

Comment: @simoco, yes, it went underground several versions ago.

Comment: I would use `DATEDIF` as Doug suggests, some elements of DATEDIF can be "buggy" and it's not in the standard function list.....but it works fine for "y" and "ym" elements AFAIK - Doug, why not post as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Alas, what I did was a simple diff and got a result in year and percent, which will work fine:

```
=((TODAY())-(D2))/365
```

The DATEDIF was a total disaster, with really odd, inconsistent results.

Thanks for all the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Microsoft Office knowledgebase](http://office.microsoft.com), I see a [YEAR](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/year-HP005209343.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP003056111) function that may be used:

```
A1: 1-Jan-2014
A2: 4-Dec-2016
A3: =YEAR(A2)-YEAR(A1) # will yield 2
```